# Drop long name procedure in Sybase

Tags: sybase, procedure, drop

I have question about Sybase. I am trying to drop procedure, which identifier is longer than 30 characters.

For example:
drop proc identifier_of_procedure_longer_than_thirty_chars

With error:
The identifier that starts with 'identifier_of_procedure_longer_than_thirty_chars' is too long. Maximum length is 30.

Don't ask me how is exactly possible to create procedure with identifier longer then 30 characters. I didn't create it. My co-workers are evidently very creative.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version are you using? what are you using as a front-end/client to connect to the database to run the `drop proc` command?

Answer (score 0):

If this is ASE ...  long identifiers (up to 255 characters) have been supported since version 15.0 (at least 17 yrs ago).

If you're receiving errors it's likely due to whatever app you're using to connect to the database. To verify this ...

You should have no problems running `drop proc` with the `isql` command line tool that comes with ASE.